# Is there a way to run pact-broker with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pact, broker

I need to set pact broker with mongodb.
I could not find any doc or link which configures pact broke with non-sql db like mongodb

Answer (score 0):

No, the Pact Broker runs with PostgreSQL or MySQL as stated on their docs. It won't work with other databases.